# push multiple value in same index value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

i'm new to javascript

Problem

```
 ['name',1,2,3,4,5]
```

i need like :-

```
['name','12345']
```

code :-

```
var abc = [];
text = 'name';
abc.push(text);
var def = [1,2,3,4,5]
$.each(def, function(index, item) {
abc.push(item);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [destruction assignment(`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const array = ['name', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [key, ...value] = array;
const result = [key, value.join('')];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var abc = [];
text = 'name';
abc.push(text);
var def = [1,2,3,4,5]
abc.push(def.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = ['name',1,2,3,4,5]

let result = [data[0],data.slice(1).join('')]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join from the end until you got the wanted length of the array.

```js
const array = ['name', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

while (array.length > 2) array.push(array.splice(array.length - 2, 2).join(''));

console.log(array);
```